# How to remove elements in a list based on another list in python, without loops?

Tags: python

I have two lists of equal length:

```
list_a = ['a','b','c','d']
list_b = [-6.3, 3.1, 0.5, 4.1]
```

I want to remove the elements < 0.7 in list_b, and simultaneously remove the corresponding elements from list_a, i.e.

```
list_a_2 = ['b','d']
list_b_2 = [3.1, 4.1]
```

I know the second list,

```
list_b_2 = [item for item in hem if item > 0.7].
```

But is there a list-thinking way to get list_a_2, without using loops?

Comment: Without using loops? Not really... A loop is probably going to be used somewhere, even if you don't explicitly write it

Comment: Try iterating over both loops at the same time, filtering qualifying items into a result list (or two).

Answer (score 6):

One way is to use `zip`:

```
list_a_2, list_b_2 = zip(*[(a, b) for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b) if b > 0.7])    
list_a_2
# ('b', 'd')

list_b_2
# (3.1, 4.1)
```

If a for loop is better suited, you can create two empty lists and conditionally append the values to them:

```
list_a_2, list_b_2 = [], []
for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b):
    if b > 0.7:
        list_a_2.append(a)
        list_b_2.append(b)

list_a_2
# ['b', 'd']

list_b_2
# [3.1, 4.1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Use a generator expression to make it nice an lazy!

Answer (score 1):

Without explicit loops, create both? Sure, if we use a temporary object:

```
list_a = ['a','b','c','d']
list_b = [-6.3, 3.1, 0.5, 4.1]
tmp = zip(a, b)
list_a_2 = [x[0] for x in tmp if x[1] > 0.7]
list_b_2 = [x[1] for x in tmp if x[1] > 0.7]
del tmp
```

But using an actual for-loop will be a bit more obvious:

```
for idx, value in enumerate(list_b):
    if value =< 0.7:
        list_a.pop(idx)
        list_b.pop(idx)
```

But you're still managing two lists for mapping (basically) keys to values.
This is what a dictionary is for! Consolidate those list and create your subset with some dictionary comprehension:

```
{x:y for x, y in zip(list_a, list_b) if y > 0.7}
```

Comment: The 3 methods are inspiring! Thank you.

Comment: I found that, by using for-loop with a long list of 3,828 elements, I could not immediately remove all the elements<0.7. Each time I ran the code, the length of lists went down. Only after four times of running, all the number less than 0.7 get kicked out. Could I avoid this problem?

Comment: It's not a good idea to remove element from a list while looping through it, which would cause problem as such. Since every time you remove the element, the length of list changes and you actually jumps over some element without checking.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to avoid loops you can use a recursive function:

```
def unnecessarily_recursive_function(list_a,list_b):
    try:
        a = list_a.pop(0)
        b = list_b.pop(0)
        tmp_a, tmp_b = unnecessarily_recursive_function(list_a,list_b)
        if b < 0.7:
            return [a] + tmp_a, [b] + tmp_b
        else:
            return tmp_a, tmp_b
    except IndexError:
        return [],[]
```

which you can call like:

```
list_a, list_b = unnecessarily_recursive_function(list_a, list_b)
```

Note that this is a really bad reason to use a recursive function and you should definitely actually go with the other suggestions above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot! For other people having a same problem:

I end up with the following code:

```
list_a = ['a','b','c','d']
list_b = [-6.3, 3.1, 0.5, 4.1]
tmp = zip(a, b)
list_a_2 = [x[0] for x in tmp if x[1] > 0.7]
list_b_2 = [x[1] for x in tmp if x[1] > 0.7]
del tmp
```

And a better idea might be directly use a dataframe to match each element with its own label.